# Imports path in react

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have a lot of imports to reducex e.g.

```
import {groupAddTeacher} from "../../../../../../redux/actions/group";
import {groupAddEvent} from "../../../../../../redux/actions/group";
```

How can I replace a path by excluding `../../../../../../`

I using webpack

```
entry: "./src/index.js",
```

Comment: If you Google "webpack absolute import" there's a bunch of articles and tutorials and such on how to get absolute importing working. The actual specific config may vary depending on your webpack version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use webpack's resolve: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

```
resolve: {
  modules: ['src/redux', 'node_modules'],
  extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'],
  unsafeCache: true,
  alias: {
    actions: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'redux', 'actions')
  }
}
```

Then you can do

```
import { groupAddEvent, groupAddTeacher } from 'actions/group';
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can give a alias in your module exports

```
alias: {
    src: path.resolve(__dirname + '/root')
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
import { groupAddTeacher }from 'root/redux/actions/group'
```